# jQuery - If hasClass but for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, random, element

This is bit hard to explain, but here goes nothing:

I have **.wrapper** that holds 50 elements with no clicking events.

On another place I have randomly loaded 5 elements out of that 50.

Now what I'm trying to do is see which 5 random elements showed up so I could turn them as clicking objects within the **.wrapper**.

For example, this is the wrapper with elements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="object1"></div>
  <div class="object2"></div>
  <div class="object3"></div>
  <div class="object4"></div>
  <div class="object5"></div>
  <div class="object6"></div>
  <div class="object7"></div>
  <div class="object8"></div>
  <div class="object9"></div>
  <div class="object10"></div>
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

And this is random container:

```
<div class="random">
  <div class="object7"></div>
  <div class="object9"></div>
  <div class="object5"></div>
  <div class="object6"></div>
  <div class="object1"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried it like this and it works but it will work only for the first one that I called and besides, there has to be a better way.

```
if ($('.random div').hasClass(".object1")){
  $(".wrapper .objects1").on("click", function() {
    // do things
  });
}

if ($('.random div').hasClass(".object2")){
  $(".wrapper .objects2").on("click", function() {
    // do things
  });
}

if ($('.random div').hasClass(".object3")){
  $(".wrapper .objects3").on("click", function() {
    // do things
  });
}

// and so on (until 50...)
```

Comment: how are you loading those elements in the `random` div are they moved from the `wrapper` div, and when you say you want to bind the `click event` do you want to perform separate actions for all of them when clicked, or they all will perform a similar action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all random divs and then get their class and select the divs inside the wrapper. Create a mapping object which holds the click handlers. You can get a specific click handler by passing the class.

If they are unique you should use rather id's.

```
var clickHandlers = {
    object7: function(e) {
        // do things for 7
    },
    object8: function(e) {
        // do things for 8
    },
    ...
};

var randomDivs = $('.random div');
$.each(randomDivs, function(index, randomDiv) {  
  var divClass = randomDiv.className;
  var wrapperDiv = $('.wrapper .'+divClass);
  wrapperDiv.on('click', clickHandlers[divClass]);
});
```

Comment: you should not answer a question based on assumptions OR you should provide a solution which satisfies all aspects.

Comment: This is a very nice approach, but unfortunately they all do different things :/

Comment: I think this might be it. I'll have to examine it a bit later but here's correct answer right away. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do the objects really need to be in separate classes? What if the structure looked like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="object" id = "obj1"></div>
  <div class="object" id = "obj2"></div>
  <div class="object" id = "obj3"></div>
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

Then you can iterate through each div with class "object" in the random div like so:

```
$('.random div').children(".object").each(function(i, obj) {
    //do things with each object
    //i is the index in the array of children with class object
    //obj is current object in the list

});
```

Comment: I might, but could you explain a bit more in detail? I'm not sure what you mean by iterate through? It's import that every div matches the same div in the wrapper